# LDAP Group object loop

Tags: vbscript, hta, ldap-query

I have an HTA file that just hangs on a process of me looping through group entries from an LDAP query.

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN) 

For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
    If "wifi user" = lcase(replace(objGroup.Name,"CN=","")) Then
        'modify my dom element here....
    End If
    If "encryption enabled" = lcase(replace(objGroup.Name,"CN=","")) Then
        'modify my dom element here....
    End If
    If "dl - some office" = lcase(replace(objGroup.Name,"CN=","")) Then
        'modify my dom element here....
   End If
Next
```

Is there a more efficient way to iterate through these groups, 80+ is a range of groups its looping and causing problems.

Or maybe I try to dump the whole list to a string and do an `InStr` query on it?

Comment: sorry, terrible example, my actual code is all lower case. late night blur... Thanks for catching and I will edit my posting.

Comment: Did you determine at which point the code hangs, the `GetObject` call or somewhere inside the loop? If the code hangs inside the loop: where exactly. If you haven't isolated the problematic statement, try adding MsgBox statements (or statements writing to a logfile) after each operation.

Comment: when I say hang, I suppose its just a hang to the HTA application. if I run my query with out the chunk above where it loops the Groups object it runs in 2 seconds on average which is simply accessing the immediate user properties. Once I add the group loop it runs at 10 seconds on average, regardless of me having anything processing on each entry in the loop. I haven't yet found what that magical number is for an HTA to go into that not responding state when a process is taking longer than normal to report back but if I could get this query at 5 seconds I think I would be in okay shape.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. guessing that `objUser.Groups` had a whole bunch of other crap in it other than just the name and the default value might have been the actual `DN` of the group I changed my for each to use `ObjUser.Groups.Name` and its immediate. going to throw it back in my HTA to validate all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code change had a dramatic improvement where looping through just a named list vs the entirety of a single group object. my PowerShell logic kicked in and got me here along with @Ansgar Wiechers prodding of testing it deeper. Thanks!

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN) 

arrGroup = objUser.MemberOf
            strGroup = ""
            For i = 0 To UBound(arrGroup)
                strGroup = arrGroup(i)

                If InStr(lcase(strGroup),"vpn user") Then
                    WScript.echo "block grp 1"
                End If
                If InStr(lcase(strGroup),"dl - some office") Then
                    WScript.echo "block grp 2"
                End If
                If InStr(lcase(strGroup),"encryption enabled") Then
                    WScript.echo "block grp 3"
                End If
                If InStr(LCase(strGroup), "wireless") Then
                    strWifi = True 
                End If 
            Next
```